# Dragging Vertices in QGIS Edit

Tags: qgis-2

I am attempting to edit a linear feature layer and need to drag vertices at node endpoints to connect across slight gaps.  In ArcMAp, it was possible to lock onto a vertex and drag it to a new position.  Does QGIS offer similar functionality? I am using Edit> Reshape Feature.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click settings and set the snapping options, this will give you the ability to lock onto other vertices. To edit vertices, next to the edit toggle (pencil symbol), there is a node tool. With this you can select and move vertices